# сборка проекта с компиляцией redux

Tags: webpack, redux

у меня есть проект на react с использованием redux. когда я пишу в файле своего проекта import redux from 'redux'; то идет импорт из директории ./node_modules/redux/lib/index.js потому что в конфигах (package.json) самого redux прописано "main": "lib/index.js". т.е. импортируется ГОТОВЫЙ скомпилированный redux.

что я хочу? я хочу взять исходники redux, т.е. импортировать не из lib/index.js, а из src/index.js. я меняю в package.json свойство main

если посмотреть теперь на мой конфиг webpack.config.js то он выглядет так:

```
...
loaders: [{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
        plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
    }
}
...
```

т.е. я явно указываю, что не нужно брать файлы для компиляции из node_modules. проблема в том, что я не знаю как прописать исключение для моего redux, что бы он компилировался. я пытался добавить ниже свойство:

```
include: /node_modules\/redux/,
```

но так webpack ругается. или хотел просто скомпилировать указав (здесь старая настройка lib/index.js):

```
include: __dirname + '/app',
```

но и с этой командой у меня не вышло. помогите с настройкой конфига

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[На гитхабе](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031) предлагают сделать как-то так:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(redux)\/).*/,
},
```

Comment: да, работает. но есть один очень важный момент! эта фишка не работает с плагином transform-runtime. т.е. если указать в loaders webpack'а plugins: ['transform-runtime'], то будет выбивать с ошибкой

Comment: @user2815962, ошибка-то какая?

Comment: компилируется без ошибок, но если попытаться открыть собранный файл, то вываливается ошибка Uncaught TypeError: $export is not a function